# how can i get URL pass value with Codeigniter in api like this : api.php?action=getCurrentOrder&grocery_id=1

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a small issue basically from till now I'm making API's with core PHP but now I'm moving with Codeigniter and I want to check with one register API but here I don't know that how can I enter my data in URL.

**In core i'm passsing data like this :**
api.php?action=userRegister&name=nitesh gupta&gender=1&email=guptanitesh40@gmail.com&mobile_number=xxxxxyyyy

**but now in Codeigniter the URL like this** 
http://localhost/ci/index.php/Mycontroller/demo/

I don't know that how can I pass data here.
can anyone help me to solve this problem with Codeigniter code?

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter v3.1.6 lets say u have this Controller

```
class MyController extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();    
    }
    public function sayHello($firstName, $lastName){
        echo 'Hello '.$firstName.' '.$lastName;
    }
}
```

Of course u want to call this function, lets assume is a link on a view

```
<a href="<?=base_url()?>MyController/sayHello/parameter1/parameter2">sayhello</a>
```

That's it, to pass de parameters instead of param1=value1&param2=value2, just send them separated with a /.

Keep in mind that codeigniter has a file ../application/config/routes.php, that file can help u to use "prettier urls", u may find uris names like

```
page.com/index.php/MyControllerThatDoesThisThing/Fuction1/param1/param2/param3
```

on that file u can create routes, an example for a long name will be (lets take 3 parametes as a example)

```
$route['short-name-(:any)-(:any)-(:any)'] = 'MyControllerThatDoesThisThing/Fuction1/$1/$2/$3'
```

and on the wview u just create the link like this

```
<a href="<?=base_url()?>short-name-value1-value2-value3"> Do Something</a>
```

Hope my answer helps u.